# Parse ASP Web API JSON Result: DateTime

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery ajax to call a Web API service. The response is Json something like this

```
     {"Id":2,"UserName":"first.last@email.com","CreatedDate":"2013-01-17T12:40:26.043","ExpireDate":"2023-01-17T12:40:26.043"}]
```

The question is: how do I bind the Createddate and Expiredate to jQuery DatePicker fields without time? So basically I need to set the value of the datepicker field something like: yyyy-mm-dd. The problem is how to parse this datetime format **2013-01-17T12:40:26.043** that will return just the yyyy-mm-dd ?

Comment: My first suggestion would be datePicker.parseDate: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it simply doing this :

```
var yourDate = '2013-01-17T12:40:26.043';

var parsedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yyyy-mm-dd', yourDate.substr(0, 10));
```

Comment: It should be `var parsedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', yourDate.substr(0, 10));` otherwise (using 'yyyy-mm-dd') it will give `Error: Missing number at position 4`